# How to add a meta keyword tag in each page of my drupal application?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, seo, meta-tags

I want to add a meta keyword tag which have to come with every pages within my drupal website. How to do that ?

Comment: do you want to add the same keywords to each page? This may be better suited to the drupal stack site...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's too easy just use the [meta tag](http://drupal.org/project/metatag) module .
And for drupal6 i found this: [Meta tags Node Type](http://drupal.org/project/nodewords_nodetype)

Welcome

Answer (score 1):

It might need a bit of tweaking but I built a module that does this.

https://github.com/SpaceBeers/Drupal-7-Meta-Tags-Module

It also lets you set a site wide default title and description which can be overridden for each node. You can select which content types this appears on.

It'd be nice to get some feed back on it.

Comment: Just realised it's D6. This is a D7 module. Might be tweakable though and the idea is sound. I'm not too hot on the differences to be honest.

Comment: I am using Drupal 6.22 version. Your module version is incompatible with the 6.22 version of Drupal core.

Comment: Yes I just commented on that. The code is all available and the ideas are sound so you should be able to adjust it for your site.

Answer (score 1):

Just add The code given below at the top of your **template.php** file (Custom).

```
drupal_set_html_head('<meta name="keywords" content="CustomKeyword" />');
```

Done.

Comment: You should never edit the core files. You'd have to apply this change again after _every_ core update.

Comment: I think index.php is a core file, too. See http://drupal.org/node/1559728 → the way to add this to Drupal would be to create a module (http://drupal.org/node/231276), or maybe change it in template.php of your custom theme (don't know if this would work)